# JavaScript: Accessing Nested Objects

Tags: javascript

The code looks like this

```
function Scripts() {this.FindById = function (id) {
    this.FindById.constructor.prototype.value = function () {
        return document.getElementById(id).value;

    }}}
```

`var Control = new Scripts();`

Now when i say Control.FindById("T1").value(). I am not able to get the textInput("T1")'s value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code is a bit more complicated then it should be ;-)

Personally I would write it this way (not tested):

```
function Scripts() {
  this.findById = function(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    return {
      value: function() { 
        return el.value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `findById()` now closes over a node and returns an interface that can return its value.

Also, your idea sounds a lot like Singleton, so you wouldn't even need the extra `Scripts` constructor:

```
var Control = {
    findById: function(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);

        return {
            value: function() { 
                return el.value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YYkD7/

Comment: Sorry my mistake it is return document.getElementById(id).value. I dont know how "=" came in between

Comment: @Rakesh sorry to hear that, but here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YYkD7/

Comment: sorry, it was working fine just that i dint check it properly.Thanks for the help man. I have on more question. How can i have more methods similar to "value" inside "FindById". Something like this                                                         var Control = {
    findById: function(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);

        return {
            value: function() { 
                return el.value;
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Rakesh You can just add your function after the `value: function() { ... }` definition.

Comment: Thanks mate, found out it has to be comma separated :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Scripts() {this.FindById = function (id) {
    this.FindById.constructor.prototype.value = function () {
        return document.getElementById(id).value
    }}}
```

You didn't close the last "}" :-)